# Unity: Trying to Link a Button to URL In a Condition "if"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, augmented-reality

I've been struggling with my AR project in Unity. The main problem is the button opens the link repeatedly and it won't stop. The concept I want to reach here is when I scanned a marker, a description text will pop up along with the button, the button will take user to a URL.
The code I'm using is:

```
public Transform ButtonMap;

TextObjectName.GetComponent<text>().text=name;

if (name == "QRCode1"){
ButtonMap.GetComponent.<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate {Application.OpenURL("https://www.google.com"); });
}
```

The code has no errors, but when I pressed it, it will open the link repeatedly until I stop the app.
Please Help

Regards

Comment: where is this located inside update or start function?

Comment: Please provide a complete code example ... You probably rather want to add your callback **ONCE** and rather check the condition within the callback method ...